# How can I check if my node is fully synced?

Tags: cardano-node

How can I check if my node is fully synced without resorting to
https://explorer.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io/ ?

Answer (score 4):

1. You can use a remote API such as [blockfrost.io](http://blockfrost.io/).
2. Since `cardano-cli` version 1.28.0, the `syncProgress` can be checked directly:

```
$ cardano-cli query tip --testnet-magic 2

{
    "epoch": 234,
    "hash": "f9eb71ac5de435b1e5c53d691cb03a4242c9cdc13f7782738e9a727a6a60aa73",
    "slot": 1684260,
    "block": 82557,
    "era": "Alonzo",
    "syncProgress": "100.00"
}
```

Comment: For future noobs (like me): to get the above response, enter the following your terminal:
`cardano-cli query tip --testnet-magic 1097911063`
(the testnet-magic number might have to be updated)